# When calling Javascript function from Silverlight, I get error "failed to invoke" the function

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I am calling a JavaScript function from Silverlight. My JavaScript file is as follows:

```
function sayHello() {
    alert("Hello from Silverlight via Javascript");
}

function showText(mytxt) {
    alert(mytxt);
}
```

In my Silverlight .cs file, I have 2 event handlers for 2 different buttons. Button1's event handler invokes sayHello(). This works perfect.

Button2's event handler invokes showText() and this one fails with error "failed to invoke showText". 
Following is my codeline from Silverlight.

```
    void myButtonClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("showText", "show this text");
    }
```

I am new to client side programming. Appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Stab in the dark:  does this work?        `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("showText", new object[] { "show this text" });`

Comment: I tried it. It did not work. I am geting the same error: "failed to invoke ShowText". Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. The problem was, the JavaScript file got cached. After I added the new method showText, I compiled it and tested it again. But the JavaScript file did not get updated, so my Silverlight application could not find the new JavaScript method showText. Clearing browser cache and Silverlight cache did not help. To get around the problem, I renamed the JavaScript file and recompiled it. This time the method got called with the parameter. 
I still need to figure out how to update the JavaScript file after making changes. I am building the JavaScript file as a resource of the dll.